# Full IPhone SE and iCloud Sync Whak-a-mole

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

I have an iPhone SE that has become problematically full (Can't update, install useful apps, or backup things like WhatsApp).

Also, the iCloud storage is full. The phone has about 6-7 years of photos (~2500 according to Photos) on it, that have been transferred from previous phones as well.

### Steps taken

I tried transferring photos to a PC by moving them out of the DCIM folder which showed about 450photos.

I tried downloading and deleting large batches of photos from iCloud. The iCloud filled up again really quickly from the iPhone. iCloud shows about 700 Photos.

**Why can't I import the other ~1300 photos direct to the computer?**

**What's the best steps to get the photos off?**

Comment: Try Windows' own Photos app [you need iTunes installed to enable this functionality.] The iPhone isn't really designed to be treated like external mass storage, though for many years Win users had to do it that way. Photos is now capable of doing the download - though idk whether it can see photos on iCloud. You may have to do it in stages, allowing the next batch to download to the phone each time first.

Comment: I tried using windows own photos app but unfortunately, importing didn't move them it just copied.

Comment: I would have expected there to be an option to change that behaviour. There is on the Mac. I've never actually seen Windows Photos, though, so I can't help with prefs etc, sorry.